Unable to use Rosdep in humble-ros-base-jammy docker image on Pi 4
As the title states im trying to use a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Lite 64bit (I've had issues with just running ubuntu so I wanted to try it) but its unable to find any rosdep packages, I know they exist as I've downloaded them on my dev machine, it just tries to run the apt-get command for my packages and it can't find them. I'm running my docker image using the command
docker run -it --rm \
    --privileged \
    --net=host \
    --mount type=bind,source=/dev/gpiomem,target=/dev/gpiomem \
    --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/ros2_ws,target=/root/ros2_ws \
    ros:humble-ros-base \
    bash

and getting an error code of
root@robot:~/ros2_ws/roomba_bot# rosdep install --from-paths src -y --ignore-src
executing command [apt-get install -y ros-humble-urdf-launch]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-urdf-launch
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-humble-urdf-launch] failed
root@robot:~/ros2_ws/roomba_bot# 

If I remove urdf-launch it just changes to being unable to find a different package, but it works fine on my WSL2 ubuntu distro. Any help is appreciated
